# Can't fully serialize List<> inheritor with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize an existing class which inherits from List<> and has members.

When I serialize it with protobuf-net it default to ListHandling which serializes the elements in the list fine but ignores the members on the list itself. If I use the "IgnoreListHandling=true" with the ProtoContract attribute, the inverse happens: members on the list are serialized but list items are lost.

I'm moving an existing application to protobuf so redesigning these kind of classes would be a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In common with several other serializers (including core .NET serializers like `XmlSerializer`), to protobuf-net, something is **either** a list **xor** a leaf. Members of a list are never considered: they *only* exist to act as a list. The `IgnoreListHandling` switches between the two modes, but the "both a list and a leaf" scenario is not supported.

Frankly, what you describe sounds like a dubious design choice *anyway*. Normally you would *encapsulate* a list, not subclass it. So rather than:

```
class MyStuff : List<Foo> {
    public int ExtraValue {get;set;}
}
```

I would strongly advocate that this should be implemented:

```
class MyStuff {
    private readonly List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
    public List<Foo> Foos { get { return foos; } }
    public int ExtraValue {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: If you want custom List then preferably implement IList<T> instead of deriving from List<T>

Comment: I personally would have designed it as you say but I'm dealing with legacy stuff. I'll try implementing IList<> while encapsulating the list in the inheritor to make this work without massive changes.

Comment: Implementing from IList has the same result, it is treated as a list just the same.